# openpyxl won't open XLSX file when extension is not .xlsx

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read an Excel XLSX file, but openpyxl won't open it, unless I explicitly give it a `.xlsx` extension. Otherwise, I get this error:

> openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm

I open the file like this:

```
wb_input = load_workbook(filename_without_extension)
```

When using `file` on the file, I see it is, in fact, an Excel 2007+ (xlsx) file.

```
[bf@localhost ~]$ file my_excel_file
my_excel_file: Microsoft Excel 2007+
```

And when copying to a filename with a `.xlsx` extension, openpyxl does open it.

How can I open a valid xlsx file without extension, using openpyxl?

Comment: The extension check is just a guard. Rename it if you're sure that it really is an OOXML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `load_workbook` also accepts a file-like object, so this works:

```
with open(filename_without_extension, "rb") as wbook:
    wb_input = load_workbook(wbook)
```